# XeLaTeX not finding font

Tags: fonts, xetex, windows

I am trying to use a template I found online, which is compiled with XeLaTeX and uses the `Fontin` font. I installed that font from [the included link](http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html), along with its "smallcaps" variant etc.

I have restarted my computer and tested the font in Microsoft Word, and it seems to be working. However, when trying to compile the document I still get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D 

l.30 ...nt[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
                                                   % Main document font
?
```

Line 30 is the following:

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font
```

Is there anything I have missed? From what I understand, XeLaTeX should be able to use all fonts on my computer, as long as they are installed through the regular way in Windows. It appears that this is not enough, though.

Comment: Your system is not up-to-date.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: What system do you mean? TeXworks' latest version is 0.4.6, which is what I have installed.

Comment: TeXworks is only an editor. The error means that the format or some files in your texsystem are not up-to-date.

Comment: That is not the message you get if a font cannot be found. It is a complaint about the code in the source it is reading. It means that you probably have mismatching versions of things installed somehow. Update your TeX installation.